# Convert Transparent PDF-Files (PDF/X-4) to either Image or PDF/X-1

Tags: image, pdf, ghostscript, cmyk

Currently we are using Ghostscript to convert CMYK-PDFs to RGB-Jpegs. Works (more or less) flawless. But during the last few weeks an increasing number of PDF-files with transparency creep up that will not be rendered correctly with our ghostscript.

So does anyone have an Idea on how to render these PDF-Files to either an image (format does not matter) or reduce the transparency so that the PDF-files comply to the PDF/X-1 standard. These files can then be rendered through our ghostscript.

A solution should be system-independent and either be accessible via an API or CLI.

The PDF-Files in question are PDF/X-4 standard PDFs containing transparency.

Ghostscript is version 9.06

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you file a bug report at [Ghostscript's bug tracker](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/) **?**

Comment: As a matter of fact, I never thought of the issue as a bug. Before I file a bug-report I want to check whether that is intended behaviour. I'll check that one again (as it is somewhat dates by now) and when it is still an issue, I'll file a bug report

Comment: Make sure to test with the latest Ghostscript (there have been about 10 releases since you initially asked your question....)

Comment: Seems like the issue has been closed with gs 9.15 - I could not reproduce it. Some test-pdfs still show issues with DeviceN-overprinting but that might also be due to missing switches and is not available in other tools as well. I therefore close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idea #1: Please report the bugs! If we don't know about them we can't fix them.....

You can report bugs at http://bugs.ghostscript.com

Comment: As a matter of fact, I never thought of the issue as a bug. Before I file a bug-report I want to check whether that is intended behaviour. I'll check that one again (as it is somewhat dates by now) and when it is still an issue, I'll file a bug report